# How to set only one value possible in column

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a question about my method. I am using JDeveloper 12c. I have a method called activeYear, which code is here:

```
public void activeYear() {
    this.getCurrentRow().setAttribute("Active", 1);
}
```

It is based on checkboxes. In my applications it works like - I have a button, which uses this method. If I press it, my current row changes his checkbox value "Active" into selected.

The point is: I must have only one row active, the every other have to be unselected when I press button immediately. How can I change this code? Or mby should I add one more method?

Solution:

To my method activeYear I added method called deactive, which code is here:

```
public void deactive() {
    RowSetIterator rowSetIterator = this.createRowSetIterator("New");
    if (rowSetIterator != null) {
        rowSetIterator.reset();
        while (rowSetIterator.hasNext()) {
          Row currentRow = rowSetIterator.next();
            currentRow.setAttribute("Active", 0);
        }
        rowSetIterator.closeRowSetIterator();
    }
}
```

Regards,
WK

Comment: set all all rows to `0` and then set the currnt row to `1`

Comment: I forgot to wrote - I am using oracle jdeveloper12c. Dear max777 - can you put any code? I would really be thankful.

Answer (score 1):

In your model layer on the set method for activeYear first find the row that currently has 1 and set it to 0 and then set the current row to 1.

Comment: @Shay_Shmeltzer - my activeYear is a transient attribute, it's located only in my VO. What Java code can get all rows of one attribute and set it's value to 0?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value of `Active` rows in all rows to `0` then set the current row to `1`

In order to do that you need to follow these steps:

**1-** create an `iterator` for your `Transient view object`, and then for each row in the `iterator` set `Active` to `0`.

```
AppModuleImpl appModule = (AppModuleImpl)(JSFUtils.getApplicationModule("YourApplicationModuleName"));
ViewObject transentViewObj = appModule.findViewObject("YourTransentViewObjectName");
RowSetIterator transentViewItr = transentViewObj.createRowSetIterator(null);

while (transentViewItr.hasNext())
{
  transentViewItr.next().setAttribute("Active", 0);
}
```

**2-** Then, you need the current row from and set the `Active` attribute to `1`

```
DCBindingContainer bindings = (DCBindingContainer)getBindings();
DCIteratorBinding iteratorBinding = bindings.findIteratorBinding("IteratoerName"); 
iteratorBinding.getCurrentRow().setAttribute("Active", 1);
```

**Note:**  you can find the `IteratoerName` as follow: go to the page-> click `bindings` tab -> you can find available `iterator`s in the `Executable` column. use exactly the same name that refer to your `view object`

Comment: Already fixed, I did very similar solution to you, but I created a method called deactive, which code is: